# Is there a Siddur authored by the Gra?

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, vilna-gaon

Is there a Siddur authored by the Gra or his talmidim that goes according to him?
If so is there a copy online?

Comment: No. The Gra never wrote a complete Siddur. (Is this a sufficient answer for you?) In fact very very very few rabbis did.

Comment: @DoubleAA “Or his talmidim that goes according to him”?

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous siddurim out there (e.g. "Siddur Ezor Eliyahu") which follow the minhagim and nusach of the Gra as laid out in his hagaos, but the Gra himself never compiled a siddur.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Siddur Ishei Yisrael, a prayerbook based on the customs of the Vilna Gaon. This scan is from a photo-offset reprint done in 1968. It is available [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Gra-Ishei-Yisrael.pdf) and contains the peirush Avnei Eliyohu including thoughts of the Gaon and his son Avrohom.

The siddur is not Siddur authored by the Gra. And there are examples included of practices with which the Gr"a did not agree e.g. it precedes Tachanun with a verse about David and Gad. Hat tip to @Double AA.

Comment: This doesn't seem to follow the Gra. For instance, I saw it precedes Tachanun with a verse about David and Gad when the Gra (and original Ashkenazi practice) was not to include such a line

Comment: @DoubleAA Point taken and answer modified.

Comment: What does it mean to be "based on the customs of the Vilna Gaon" if it misses clear customs he had?